# NoReverseMatch in Django after create Object

Tags: django

After creating an object without template, I am trying to return to the same list view but it sends the reverse match error.

This is my code:

Function to create an object from other model:

```
def pieza_fast_create(request, id_reporte):
 template_name = "metalitec/reportes_detalle.html"
 context_object_name = "obj"

 reporte = Reporte.objects.get(id=id_reporte)
 pieza=Pieza.objects.create(reporte=reporte, descripcion="PIEZA 1")

 piezas = Pieza.objects.all()

 return render(request, template_name, {'id_reporte':id_reporte,'reporte':reporte, 'piezas':piezas})
```

Current View:

```
class ReporteDetalleView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
 model = Reporte
 template_name = "metalitec/reportes_detalle.html"
 context_object_name = "obj"
 #login_url = "bases:login"

 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):        
    id_reporte = kwargs['id_reporte']

    reporte = Reporte.objects.filter(id=id_reporte) 
    piezas = Pieza.objects.filter(reporte__id=id_reporte)        

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'id_reporte':id_reporte, 'reporte':reporte, 'piezas':piezas})
```

URLs:

```
path('reportes/piezas/fast/<int:id_reporte>',pieza_fast_create, name='pieza_new_fast'),    
path('reportes/detalle/<int:id_reporte>',ReporteDetalleView.as_view(), name='reporte_detalle'),
```

Error:

```
Reverse for 'pieza_new_fast' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['metalitec/reportes/piezas/fast/(?P<id_reporte>[0-9]+)$']
```

Comment: please share your templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rendering the template `metalitec/reportes_detalle.html` again, it is better to redirect to that view `ReporteDetalleView`. You can try like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def pieza_fast_create(request, id_reporte):    
     reporte = Reporte.objects.get(id=id_reporte)
     pieza=Pieza.objects.create(reporte=reporte, descripcion="PIEZA 1")
     return redirect('reporte_detalle', id_reporte=id_reporte)
```

Also, you can add some improvements to your code like this:

```
class ReporteDetalleView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
     model = Reporte
     template_name = "metalitec/reportes_detalle.html"
     slug_url_kwarg = "id_reporte"
     context_object_name = "reporte"

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):        
        context = super(ReporteDetalleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        reporte = context["reporte"]
        context["piezas"] = Pieza.objects.filter(reporte=reporte)
        context["id_reporte"] = self.kwargs["id_reporte"]
        return context
```